# Ruby call child method from parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, superclass

I'm writing a program in rails where one class has the same behavior as another class. The only difference is that there is a class variable, `@secret_num`, that is calculated differently between the two classes.  I would like to call a particular super class method, but use the class variable from the child class. What is tricky is that the class variable is not a constant so I am setting it within its own method. Is there any way to do what I'm attempting to do below? 
Thanks

```
Class Foo
  def secret
    return [1,2,3].sample
  end

  def b
    @secret_num = secret
    ... # lots of lines of code that use @secret_num
  end
end

Class Bar < Foo
  def secret
    return [4, 5, 6].sample
  end

  def b
    super    # use @secret_num from class Bar.
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because the call to `super` also called the parent class's `secret` method, i.e. `Foo#secret`, but I need to use the secret number from the child class, i.e. `Bar#secret`.

Comment: Does it have to be a class variable? How about an attribute?

Comment: FWIW, as the chosen answer shows, you don't need to use an explicit return statement in your method declarations. Ruby will automatically return the last statement in a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo
  def secret
    [1,2,3].sample
  end

  def b(secret_num = secret)
    <lots of lines of code that use secret_num>
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def secret
    [4, 5, 6].sample
  end
end
```

Note, you don't need to pass `secret` as an argument to `b`. As long as you don't redefine `b` in the subclass, inheritance will take care of calling the correct implementation of `secret`.

My preference is to have it as an argument so I can pass in various values in testing.